# Serilog-Sinks-Loki transmitting logs to Loki in big batches. How can I reduce batch amount?

Tags: c#, logging, httpclient, serilog

I am trying to send my logs from .netcore 3.1 API to Loki server. For doing that I'm using Serilog-Sinks-Loki nugget package.
When I run my code, logs are sent immediately and I can see them in Grafana. As time past, logs are coming with delay which growing bigger and bigger. Eventually I see my logs arriving after delay of 10 minutes to Loki.
I read about that and understand that Serilog-Sinks-Loki sits on top of Serilog-Sinks-Http so I need to configure something over there to make my logs arrive faster but not sure how, can someone help me with that please?
My goal is to send my logs immediately, with no delay.

Here is my program.cs code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseLamar()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {

                    var credentials = new BasicAuthCredentials("LOKI-SERVER-URL", "USER", "PASSWORD");
                    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                            .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                            .WriteTo.LokiHttp(credentials)
                            .CreateLogger();
                    logging.AddSerilog(log);
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `Serilog.Sinks.Loki` wraps a `Serilog.Sinks.Http` sink, [it doesn't expose any of the settings](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.Http/LoggerSinkConfigurationExtensions.cs) that would allow you to configure how often messages are sent ([`batchPostingLimit`, `period`, etc.](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/serilog-sinks-http/blob/master/src/Serilog.Sinks.Http/LoggerSinkConfigurationExtensions.cs#L167-L172))

That said, the default period of `Sinks.Sink.Http` is 2 seconds, thus 10 minutes is too long for messages to be sent with the default settings. You're likely having connection issues that are blocking the sink from sending the messages or blocking the server from receiving them.

Have you tried enabling the [`SelfLog`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics#selflog) to see if any errors are being caught by the sink?

If not, you can monitor the network traffic to see if you can find failed attempts and/or timeouts when the sink tries to send the log events.

You can also [extend the LokiHttpClient](https://github.com/JosephWoodward/Serilog-Sinks-Loki#custom-http-client) and write some debug messages to a file or something to see how often / how many messages are being sent.

For reference here is a recent issue in the `Serilog.Sinks.Loki` repo (perhaps you created it?)

> [Logs are been sent as a batch once in 10 minutes #26](https://github.com/JosephWoodward/Serilog-Sinks-Loki/issues/26)

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, here and in GitHub, yes that was me.
It is very strange. Because earlier today I noticed that all my logs arrives at one big chunk every 10 minutes (precisely) it seems like a pattern.(It happened when I ran my code locally by VS and even after I've published my code to Azure web app)
Now you inform me that default period is 2 seconds and I looked at grafana again and it seems like logs are arrives in few seconds.
I can't explain that behavior except that maybe Loki server had connectivity issues.
Anyway thank you so much!